# Copying my Fifa 14 PC player

Tags: fifa-14

Is it possible to copy my FIFA 14 PC player to my FIFA 14 PC on my other laptop? I want to avoid creating him over all over again. I went to the path where my FIFA game is saved but am not seeing any indication of that created player data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it it.!

Save the squad in the game it is available right now.

copy the saved squad file to new pc.

load the squad and save the profile
and the player will be there in game :)